# Frameset not displaying in Lotus Notes Application when user opens database

Tags: lotus-notes

We have an application that is written in 8.0.3 and we are using a frameset.  When the user opens the database, the frameset doesn't display all of the time.  In the database setting, we have it set to open the frameset.  Can anyone tell me why it isn't always displaying?

Comment: What does it display rest of the times?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens because it cannot find or load the contents of one or more frames.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the user has no rights to open an element from the frameset. 
Some design elements may have access protection.

Answer (score 0):

See [Notes/Domino 6 and 7 Forum](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/DateAllFlatweb/df77395cec0437448525740200691a33?OpenDocument) for the same issue answered.

This happens when one of the frame contents cannot be found.
Open the properties of each Frame within the Frameset and examine the Value. You may need to click the @ button to view the View reference, make sure that the element linked to actually exists.